# IIS application start does not wait for Okta middleware and returns 401

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, okta

I am using Okta to secure a Rest API.
The application is hosted on IIS 10.0 on Win server 2019.

This works when the web application is already loaded.

But when the application is unloaded after 20 minutes the first Okta secured request receives an 401 Unauthorized.
It works doing the same request some seconds later with the same token.

It looks like the middleware setup takes too long and the request is answered before this is done with the "Unauthorized" response.

Can anyone help me out here with some information what I am doing wrong?

This is my startup class:

```
    public class Startup
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("root");
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        log.Debug("Do Configuration");

        string oktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Okta:OktaDomain"];
        string oktaAuthorizationServerId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Okta:AuthorizationServerId"];
        string oktaAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Okta:Audience"];
        string oktaAuthority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Okta:Authority"];

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        var authority = oktaAuthority;

        var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                          authority + "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
        new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
        new HttpDocumentRetriever());
       
        var discoveryDocument = Task.Run(() => configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        log.Debug("Setting up Okta authentication");
        try
        {
            app.UseOktaWebApi(new OktaWebApiOptions
            {
        
                OktaDomain = oktaDomain
                ,AuthorizationServerId = oktaAuthorizationServerId
                ,Audience = oktaAudience
            });

            #region old code    
            //app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            //   new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            //   {
            //       //token handler set to try to debug issues on prod and dev
            //       //TokenHandler = new LoggingJwtSecurityTokenHandler(),
            //       AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            //       TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            //       {
            //           ValidAudience = "api://default",
            //           ValidIssuer = authority,
            //           IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
            //           {
            //               return discoveryDocument.SigningKeys;
            //           }
            //       }
            //   }); ;
            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error setting up Okta authentication", ex);
            throw;
        }

        log.Debug("Map configuration");
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;

        app.UseWebApi(config);
        
        log.Debug("Configuration done");


    }


}
```

Adding a Sleep before returning from the method helps to make it work. I can't imaginge that this is the intended behavior.

```
        app.UseWebApi(config);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);  <--- adding this line helps.

        log.Debug("Configuration done");
```

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? Upgrade to at least .NET 6 and test again.

Comment: Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to see details about 401 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: @LexLi It is running on .net 4.8. I don't want to upgrade the tool if not required. I would expect that the same thing is working on .net 4.8 as well and not only in .net 6. Or did something change fundamentally?

Comment: @samwu I created a failed request trace but I did not find any explanation in it.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the failed request tracing log?